# Creating a DOM NodeList

Tags: javascript, dom, e4x

I'm implementing all of the optional E4X features described in ECMA-357 Annex A and I'm having trouble implementing domNodeList (§A.1.2 and §A.2.2). How would I create my own NodeList object?

Even if I create a new XMLDocument and append every domNode() representation of the nodes in an XMLList, I still don't see how I could create a NodeList containing everything as comments and processing instructions are usually excluded.

Comment: What is the context of this question?  What are you writing?

Comment: Ryan, do you not see domNodeList? I also clearly state where it's defined in ECMA-357.

Comment: Crescent: So the best solution can be put in the post by any commenter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out that I could use the childNodes attribute of a document fragment to create a NodeList. This was my solution:

```
XML.prototype.function::domNodeList = function () {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    len = this.length(),
    i = 0;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        fragment.appendChild(this[i].domNode());
    }
    return fragment.childNodes;
}
```

Comment: This removes the added node/s from the dom