# Create node list from a single node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodes, nodelist

This is one of those it seems so simple, but I cannot come up with a good way to go about it.

I have a node, maybe `nodelist = document.getElementById("mydiv");` - I need to normalize this to a node list. And not an array either: an actual, bona-fide `nodeList` object.

**Not** `nodelist = [document.getElementById("mydiv")];`

No libraries, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a DOM NodeList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776769/creating-a-dom-nodelist)

Comment: Very similar... slightly different implementation. Good to have that reference here though.

Comment: Given the issue's with my answer, could you please un-accept my answer in order that I might delete it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reviving this because I recently remembered something about *JavaScript*. This depends on how the *NodeList* is being checked, but..

```js
const singleNode = ((nodeList) => (node) => {
  const layer = { // define our specific case
    0: { value: node, enumerable: true },
    length: { value: 1 },
    item: {
      value(i) {
        return this[+i || 0];
      }, 
      enumerable: true,
    },
  };
  return Object.create(nodeList, layer); // put our case on top of true NodeList
})(document.createDocumentFragment().childNodes); // scope a true NodeList
```

Now, if you do

```
const list = singleNode(document.body); // for example

list instanceof NodeList; // true
list.constructor === NodeList; // true
```

and `list` has properties *length* `1` and *0* as your node, as well as anything inherited from *NodeList*.

If you can't use `Object.create`, you could do the same except as a constructor with prototype `nodelist` and set `this['0'] = node;`, `this['length'] = 1;` and create with `new`.

---

ES5 version

```
var singleNode = (function () {
    // make an empty node list to inherit from
    var nodelist = document.createDocumentFragment().childNodes;
    // return a function to create object formed as desired
    return function (node) {
        return Object.create(nodelist, {
            '0': {value: node, enumerable: true},
            'length': {value: 1},
            'item': {
                "value": function (i) {
                    return this[+i || 0];
                }, 
                enumerable: true
            }
        }); // return an object pretending to be a NodeList
    };
}());
```

Comment: Also going to point out that if you want to use `list.item`, you'll have to shadow it to avoid an illegal invocation (perhaps use two-level prototyping).

Comment: I appreciate that it's been several years, by why does `singleNode` return a self-executing function? It seems to work fine by just returning the `Object.create...` after creating the empty `DocumentFragment`? Is it just so the document fragment is created once, no matter how many times it's called?

Comment: @RegularJo yep, as we're putting the document fragment in the prototype and not modifying it we can re-use the same fragment as many times as we'd like if we capture it in a scope

Comment: Updated for ES6

Answer (score 10):

Take any element already referenced in JavaScript, give it an attribute we can find using a selector, find it as a list, remove the attribute, return the list.

```
function toNodeList(elm){
    var list;
    elm.setAttribute('wrapNodeList','');
    list = document.querySelectorAll('[wrapNodeList]');
    elm.removeAttribute('wrapNodeList');
    return list;
}
```

Extended from bfavaretto's answer.

---

```
function toNodeList(elm, context){
    var list, df;
    context = context // context provided
           || elm.parentNode; // element's parent
    if(!context && elm.ownerDocument){ // is part of a document
        if(elm === elm.ownerDocument.documentElement || elm.ownerDocument.constructor.name === 'DocumentFragment'){ // is <html> or in a fragment
            context = elm.ownerDocument;
        }
    }
    if(!context){ // still no context? do David Thomas' method
        df = document.createDocumentFragment();
        df.appendChild(elm);
        list = df.childNodes;
        // df.removeChild(elm); // NodeList is live, removeChild empties it
        return list;
    }
    // selector method
    elm.setAttribute('wrapNodeList','');
    list = context.querySelectorAll('[wrapNodeList]');
    elm.removeAttribute('wrapNodeList');
    return list;
}
```

---

There is another way to do this I thought of recently

```
var _NodeList = (function () {
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.appendChild(document.createComment('node shadows me'));
    function NodeList (node) {
        this[0] = node;
    };
    NodeList.prototype = (function (proto) {
        function F() {} // Object.create shim
        F.prototype = proto;
        return new F();
    }(fragment.childNodes));
    NodeList.prototype.item = function item(i) {
        return this[+i || 0];
    };
    return NodeList;
}());
```

Now

```
var list = new _NodeList(document.body); // note **new**
list.constructor === NodeList; // all these are true
list instanceof NodeList;
list.length === 1;
list[0] === document.body;
list.item(0) === document.body;
```

Comment: You're saying you can't necessarily access the element you want with any CSS selector?

Comment: Yes. The node could have been dynamically created or selected from the document.

Comment: @RandyHall edit should work in almost any situation (with the exception of `elm.nodeType !== 1`)

Comment: So basically, if it's in the document or a context container, do your method, if it's not, David Thomas' method would be safe. Nice.

Comment: I don't know why you're unhappy with an Array, though. Other than as a mental challenge. If you don't care how the NodeList is created then it's "live-ness" isn't of much importance, and nearly all methods and properties are the same as those on arrays. (You can add _item_ with `Array.prototype.item = function(i){return this[i];};`)

Comment: In most cases, you'd be completely correct. But there's functions written by others that I have to utilize but cannot affect that require and check for a nodelist specifically.

Comment: @RandyHall I recently had some inspiration about this. I'm not sure how the check was done, but I'm pretty sure this will pass it. **edit** oh, I see I posted another answer to do the same that's further down, lol.. well at least the way I wrote it this time works in older browsers and has a little less to do each construction D:

Comment: Not working on Firefox and Chrome. 3rd condition is raising `Invalid Invocation` error on Chrome. 4th and 5th conditions are evaluating to `false` on Firefox, but `true` on Chrome.

Comment: I liked the tag, fetch, and untag approach better, but used a data attribute to ensure no collision with anything else on the element: https://gist.github.com/GuyPaddock/93fbe863389a88fc9f2d495446c2598c

Comment: @Paul Your approach is very smart!

Answer (score 8):

If you're targeting browsers that support [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), it will always return a `NodeList`. So:

```
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll("#mydiv");
```

Comment: Good thought as well, however that's not ALWAYS how I'm getting my node. +1 for idea other may find relevant and useful!

Answer (score 7):

Yet another way to do this based on Reflect.construct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct

As in other cases it requires patching NodeList.prototype.item to make calls to this function work.

```
NodeList.prototype.item = function item(i) {
    return this[+i || 0];
};
let nl = Reflect.construct(Array, [], NodeList);
```

To create it with nodes pass array of nodes as second argument.
This method passes checks:

```
list instanceof NodeList; // true
list.constructor === NodeList; // true
```

Array, created with it, is iterable with `for..of`, `forEach` and other standard methods and you can add elements into it with simple `nl[n] = node;`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the item declaration and `+i` syntax (never seen that before) but Reflect.construct() works well.

Comment: I take it back... in Safari 12 we get "TypeError: Reflect.construct requires the third argument to be a constructor if present".

Comment: Well, you can try to play with this then:

    div.parentNode.querySelectorAll(`:scope > :nth-child(${Array.from(div.parentNode.children).indexOf(div)+1})`)

Not sure about compatibility with Safari 12 and it won't work in IE11 for sure, but it returns actual NodeList. Element must have a parent, though. Could be solved by temporarily adding it into another element in case parentNode is null.

Comment: You don't even need to patch the prototype anymore!

Answer (score 3):

```
var nodeList = document.createDocumentFragment();
nodeList.appendChild(document.getElementById("myDiv"));
```

Comment: But `nodeList instanceof NodeList` returns false.

Comment: You can return the nodeList after appending like such:
`console.log(nodeList.childNodes instanceof NodeList); // returns true`

Comment: The problem with this is that adding the node to the fragment removes it from the document DOM.

Comment: This is handy for writing unit tests